# Is there an alternative to indexOf for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I'm in the process of refining a translation script, and the script itself actually works fine (on most computers). We've found that the script does not work correctly on computers where the native language is not English.

The script is as follows:

```
$('.translation-links a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var lang = $(this).data('lang');
      $('#google_translate_element select option').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(lang) != -1) {
            $(this).parent().val($(this).val());
            var container = document.getElementById('google_translate_element');
            var select = container.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
            triggerHtmlEvent(select, 'change');
        }
    });
});
```

The `.translation-links a` would be something like:

```
 <li><a href="#" data-country="south-africa" data-lang="Afrikaans"><span class="south-africa"></span>Afrikaans</a></li>
```

The line with the problem is

```
if($(this).text().indexOf(lang) != -1) {
```

We've narrowed it to that line through troubleshooting, but we're wondering if there is another way to write it to possibly prevent the issue. Maybe an alternative to indexOf?  We're not sure exactly why the native language matters, so if somebody has some insight into that as well we'd appreciate it!

Comment: Can you show what's in `$(this).text`?

Comment: $(This).text pulls the language that the user selected. So if they clicked the Afrikaans button $(this) would be equal to Afrikaans

Comment: And what's in `lang` then? I mean, if you narrow the issue to a single line, could you show the whole set of data this line deals with?

Comment: `indexOf` isn't jQuery - it's a part of the window API (usually). `$.inArray` is jQuery's eqvivalent

Comment: I'll throw up an example of the translation link so you can see what data pulls.

Comment: @Johan not equivalent regarding using indexOf() on string. `$.inArray()` is to handle older browsers without any `Array.prototype.indexOf` method. But IIRC, all browsers support `String.prototype.indexOf` method

Comment: So `var lang` is equal to the `data-lang` of the link.

Comment: Do you see the same text on the browsers with other native languages? I mean, won't they have the language labels translated?

Comment: You're right. That's the problem, the languages don't match up because they've already been translated...

Comment: But the values (language prefixes) stay the same regardless.  For example, Spanish vs. Espanol, but both have a `value` of 'es'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should be looking for a match between the clicked elements' `data-lang` string and an option's `value`, both of which should be immune to translation.

If so, then it should be as simple as :

```
$('.translation-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#google_translate_element select').eq(0).val($(this).data('lang')).trigger('change');
});
```